# Search a hierarchy of class and return the path to get there

Tags: c#

I have this class, a hierarchy of categories.

```
class Categories
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public List<Categories> ChildrenData { get; set; }
}
```

How can I recursively iterate through this class of unknown depth and return the path to get there?

All "Id" values are unique. Say I want to find Id = 23 and get the path to get there by concatenating "Name".

For example, in the image below searching for ID = 23 would return: Default Category/Books/Nonfiction/Best-sellers

Example Hierarchy

[image: Example Hierarchy]

Comment: How much do you know about recursive functions in c#? Also, side note, it's better to have class names singular ("Catagory") rather than plural.

Comment: Is there a reason for the _Magento_ tag? This seems to be a _C#_ question and unrelated to _PHP_...

Comment: @gunr2171 It doesn't have to be recursive, I thought it may be the only solution.  This is a for a json response from magento2 not sure if the tag should be here or not

Comment: **Do you have a method that takes an `Id` and returns a `Category`**? If you have that then the problem becomes very straightforward. If you do not, it's quite a bit harder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion is that you first build an index:

```
public static Dictionary<long, Category> IndexBuilder(Category c)
{
  var index = new Dictionary<long, Category>();
  IndexBuilder(c, index);
  return index;
}

private static void IndexBuilder(Category c, Dictionary<long, Category> index)
{
  if (index.ContainsKey(c.Id))
    return;
  index[c.Id] = c;
  foreach(var child in c.ChildrenData)
    IndexBuilder(child, index);
}
```

Now you have a lookup, and your path is then easy to produce:

```
static IEnumerable<Category> PathToRoot(long id, Dictionary<long, Category> index)
{
  // Presumably the parent id of the top category is a sentinel.
  long current = id
  while (current != 0)
  {
    var category = index[current];
    yield return category;
    current = category.ParentId;
  }
}
```

Or maybe we just go until we run out of index:

```
static IEnumerable<Category> PathToRoot(long id, Dictionary<long, Category> index)
{
  long current = id
  while (index.ContainsKey(current))
  {
    var category = index[current];
    yield return category;
    current = category.ParentId;
  }
}
```

Now you have a tool you can use to make your string:

```
static string Slash<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items) =>
  string.Join("/", items);

var s = PathToRoot(23, index)
  .Reverse()
  .Select(c => c.Name)
  .Slash();
```

See what I am doing here? **Make a bunch of helper methods each of which is about five lines long**, that can be composed together to make powerful solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I have provided 2 ways, the first way is recursive and the last is not.

Recursive way, add a reference to your parent. This way when you find a match you can easily traverse your way back up the chain to create your path.

```
class Categories
{
   public Categories Parent { get; set; }

   public long Id { get; set; }

   public long ParentId { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }

   public bool IsActive { get; set; }

   public List<Categories> ChildrenData { get; set; }
}
```

Then add a Find() method:

```
public string Find(long id)
{
   if( Id == id ) 
   {
    return GetPath(); //<-- we need to code this next. 
   }
   else
   {
      foreach( var entry in Categories)
      {
         string path = entry.Find(id);
         if( path != null )
         {
             return path;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```

And finally the GetPath(), the assumption here is that the highest level instances of Categories do not have a Parent:

```
public string GetPath()
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Categories current = this;
    while( current != null)
    {
        sb.Insert(0,current.Name);        
        if( current != this)
        {
           sb.Insert(0,"/");        
        }
        current = Parent;
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Now if recursion isn't what you want, then pass in the current path to the `Find()` method.

```
public string Find(long id, string pathSoFar)
{
    if (pathSoFar == null)
    {
       pathSoFar = Name;
    }
    else
    {
       pathSoFar = pathSoFar + Name;
    }

    if ( Id == id)
    {
       return pathSoFar;
    }
    else
    {
      foreach( var entry in Categories)
      {
         string path = entry.Find(id, pathSoFar + "/");
         if( path != null )
         {
             return path;
         }
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var nonRecusive = cats.Find(23, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get what you are looking for using recursion:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = GetData();

    Console.WriteLine(GetPath(data, 23, ""));
}

public String GetPath(Categories c, Int32 id, String path)
{   
    if (c.Id == id)
    {
        return path + "/" + c.Name;
    }

    foreach (var cd in c.ChildrenData)
    {
        var p = GetPath(cd, id, path + "/" + c.Name);
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p))
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return "";
}

public class Categories
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public List<Categories> ChildrenData { get; set; }
}

public Categories GetData()
{
    return
        new Categories
        {
            Id = 1,
            Name = "Default Category",
            ChildrenData = new List<Categories>
            {
                    new Categories
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "Magazines",
                        ChildrenData = new List<Categories> {}
                    },
                    new Categories
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        Name = "Books",
                        ChildrenData = new List<Categories>
                        {
                            new Categories
                            {
                                Id = 20,
                                Name = "Fiction",
                                ChildrenData = new List<Categories> {}
                            },
                            new Categories
                            {
                                Id = 21,
                                Name = "Nonfiction",
                                ChildrenData = new List<Categories>
                                {
                                    new Categories
                                    {
                                        Id = 22,
                                        Name = "New",
                                        ChildrenData = new List<Categories> {}
                                    },
                                    new Categories
                                    {
                                        Id = 23,
                                        Name = "Best-Sellers",
                                        ChildrenData = new List<Categories> {}
                                    },
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
            }
        };
}
```